# Can't create itunesconnect sandbox tester

Tags: ios

I'm stuck with itunesconnect. For testing my in-app purchase code of an iOS app I try to create a sandbox tester account, but all I get is "An unknown error has occurred." 
As email address I use a gmail address like "myname+us@gmail.com" which is not an existing Apple ID.
The only weird thing I can see is the date-of-birth thing where I can specify month and day only (no year). 
Has anyone experienced the same problem? Is that a problem inside itunesconnect or what can I do here? Any help is appreciated.
Andreas

Comment: I can confirm that itunesconnect will reject common disposable emails.
I had luck with pokemail.com (from guerrillamail.com) though.

Comment: i have tried using this trick but it won't work for me when i am going to add + sign in real email its showing me weird error like "this field is invalid" in password textbox but if i use "_" instead of "+" it will work. but can't get any verification mail please help you guys have solved this problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was just running into the same issue.  I was able to finally get a test account through when i removed the +abcd from my address and just used another account I have.

So even though they say to use the +abcd thing it throws and "Unknown Error" when you try and use it.

Comment: You're right. I've just created successfully a sandbox tester with a standard email address. This is weird, because the iTunes Connect Developers Guide suggests explicitely to use subaddresses. See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html

Comment: Tried user1@spam4.me and user1@grr.la emails (there are from temp email service) without any luck...

Comment: i have tried using this trick but it won't work for me when i am going to add + sign in real email its showing me weird error like "this field is invalid" in password textbox but if i use "_" instead of "+" it will work. but can't get any verification mail please help you guys have solved this problem

Answer (score 16):

I had to use at least 1 upper case, 1 special char (like @), 1 punctuation mark and 1 lower case and be at least 8 digits long

I was getting simply 'This field is invalid' in the password when submitting - no guidance at all as to what was wrong - great UX Apple

Comment: - Thanks, it works. Password validation issue in my case. You are correct apple need to provide proper validation message at there.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error, but this wasn't my issue. In my case, I had created throwaway accounts that had 3 parts in the domain part of the email address - e.g. foo.bar.com. It turns out that won't work for iTunes, but two parts work fine - e.g. foo.com.

Thanks Apple for such a wonderfully opaque error message. Loved wasting a few hours on this.

Answer (score 8):

The problem for me was a weak password..

You need to use a "strong" password (at least 1 capital letter, 1 number and 1 punctuation char).

Really weird that the error message is unknown.

Comment: This worked for me. Was also getting a "not helpful" error message. Cheers Apple!

Answer (score 7):

This is undocumented Apple behavior. They will block registration of email addresses that:

- Are already used on production app store
- Are already used on production app store but also use the `+` trick to make a sub mailbox on Gmail
- Are mailinator addresses
- Are mailinator addresses but using an alternate domain (ayfs? yiafs.)

**SOLUTION**

1. Create an MX record on a domain you control: `anon.domain.com` -> `mail.mailinator.com`
2. Register an address like `bob@anon.domain.com`
3. Now you can get the mail on mailinator for the mailbox named `bob`

Answer (score 3):

Seems like using the `@example.com` domain for email will return that error as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use temporary email address to test IAPs and got the same problem. As soon as I changed it to popular email service - I was allowed to add it as sandbox tester.

Summarize everything that were said, looks like probably *Apple doesn't allow to use fake or suspicious email addresses* for that purposes.

Answer (score 1):

For me, when I used the email ending with

> @icloud.com

none of the above method worked I tried keeping strong password including `1 punctuation , 1 Upper, 1 Lower, 1 Special and atleast 1 number`.

But as soon as I changed the domain to

> @gmail.com

keeping the same configuration like above it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me. Than opened a fresh gmail account and it worked.