# Can't create itunes connect sandbox tester

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, applepay

There are many topics **(Old and new)** related with this. Unfortunately I am having a lot of problems to create a simple ***Sandbox Tester Account***.

My error is:

> **There are one or more validation errors below.**

The problem is that what the message says is false, there are no indications about what is wrong.

**I have made many attempts:**

- Use an account that exists as an internal tester by testlight.
- Create an account from an existing gmail account.
- Create a new account with domain `@icloud`.

But nothing works. :(

I have also tried that the passwords have some capital letter, some special character and numbers.

Even i adding `+something` in email but the error changes to

> **An error has occurred. Try again later.**

I'm trying to follow all recommendations from the next threads:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/349819#349819

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/349820#349820

[Can't create itunesconnect sandbox tester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703713/cant-create-itunesconnect-sandbox-tester)

Comment: This was happening to me the other day too! I wonder if it's an issue on Apple's end.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue right now, also trying a gmail w/ +something. The fact that, while googling for a solution, I stumbled across this question asked today, makes me think it could be a temporary issue on Apple's end.

Comment: Ah ok, in my situation I was able to create a new tester by using a different gmail account I was 100% sure was not an existing Apple ID. Not sure why the alias (+something) didn't work, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create sandbox tester now.

I'm doing some wrong, you need put a no existent account.

I explain:

[image]

This form apparently create a new apple account. Just create the account first here, after login with this email in your iphone and after create a gmail account to verify the account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an email Id which is not previously associated with the apple Id. Fresh email Id worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Still happening in 2023 and the reason is weak password. If you enter a password which all characters are letters, it will show error that you need at least one digit.

If you add that and your password now contains letters and digit, there is no error message any more but Create button does not work no matter how many times you try.

If you add one additional symbol to the password it will work and your sandbox test account created now. So the password should at least contain letters, digits and one symbol.